# Is it possible to disable aggressive indent mode per file extension?

Tags: package, web-mode

Would it be possible to disable [aggressive indent package](https://github.com/Malabarba/aggressive-indent-mode) just for some file extensions?. I know it's possible to do it by major mode, but I use web-mode for js,html,php and others. And I just want to disable it for javascript.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```el
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook #'(lambda ()
                             (unless (and (stringp buffer-file-name)
                                          (string-match "\\.js\\'" buffer-file-name))
                               (aggressive-indent-mode))))
```

It activates `aggressive-indent-mode` only if file extension is not `js`.

If you use `(global-aggressive-indent-mode 1)` you can disable it per this:

```el
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook #'(lambda ()
                             (when (and (stringp buffer-file-name)
                                        (string-match "\\.js\\'" buffer-file-name))
                               (aggressive-indent-mode 0))))
```

And finally, to disable it in javascript sections use these advices:

```el
(defun aggressive-indent-advice (org-fun &rest args)
  "Do not agressive-indent in javascript section of web-mode."
  (let ((agressive-indent t))
    (when (equal major-mode 'web-mode)
      (setq agressive-indent
            (not (member (get-text-property (point) 'part-side) '(javascript)))))
    (when agressive-indent
      (apply org-fun args))))
(advice-add 'aggressive-indent--keep-track-of-changes :around #'aggressive-indent-advice)
(advice-add 'aggressive-indent--indent-if-changed :around #'aggressive-indent-advice)
(advice-add 'aggressive-indent--softly-indent-defun :around #'aggressive-indent-advice)
```

Note that, depending on your need, you can use the former two hooks independently from `web-mode` to disable `aggressive-indent`. On the other hand, the depends on `web-mode`, but will also work for `.js` files in `web-mode`.

Comment: I would suggest to wrap the bare lambda in a separate function so that (1) it is convenient to quickly add/remove that function from the hook (2) `C-h v FOO-hook` would be more legible. *Also, lambdas do not need to be (hash-)quoted.*

Comment: I'm using `(global-aggressive-indent-mode 1)` so I used your second choice but it doesn't seem to work, even when I open a `.js` file `aggressive-mode` is still enabled.

Comment: Yes, it stays enabled, but it should have be used in `javascript` sections. The advice decides to either call the indenter `apply org-fun` or to do nothing. It decides based on the `web-mode` property. Note that the post was not correct and you should update your code: `(not (member (get-text-property (point) 'part-side) '(javascript)))))`.